# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'T'

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Here I have two lines of code run in ipython on a large text file that I previously read in of tab-separated values and already split by line:

```
In [30]: data = [(int(e[0]),e[1],e[2],int(e[3])) for e in d.split('\t') for d in dat]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/max/verk/data/build/x86_64/bin/ipython in <module>()
----> 1 data = [(int(e[0]),e[1],e[2],int(e[3])) for e in d.split('\t') for d in dat]

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'T'

In [31]: data = [(int(e[0]),e[1],e[2],int(e[3])) for e in (d.split('\t') for d in dat)]

In [32]: len(data)
Out[32]: 173503

In [33]:
```

... So what happened here? Why does the code on line 30 not work, and why does the error look like it's having trouble converting a string to int, when the solution seems to be related to list comprehension?

Comment: The list comprehension is converting strings to ints. The error says that you tried to convert a `'T'` to an int, which obviously won't work.

Comment: why downvote when you didn't bother to read the question

Comment: That _is_ odd, actually. (Also, I didn't downvote) But line 30 is wrong, because you're referencing `d` (in `d.split()`) before it's defined (in `for d in dat`).

Comment: If you already have another variable called `d`, that could be causing the confusion with `int`.  Without the parentheses, the list comprehension is evaluated from left-to-right (see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#list-displays)).

Comment: Aha! That's what it was. If you want to write that as a complete answer I'll give you the check mark